# Human-readable URL change

Tags: seo

Question is the following, we have site with video. Where address is video title, which can changing all the time. For example user upload video and name it "nice video" then he rename it to "nice video in London". So in this case URL also changed from "http://example.com/video123/nice-video" to http://example.com/video123/nice-video-in-london.

From my research I found that dailymotion using canonical pointing to the page without any keywords in the URL (example.com/video123). So question which URL will be in SERP?

Question, how should we care of this? Thank you so much in advance for any suggestions on it.

Regards,
Constantine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You will put in the canonical link the link of the page that you intent to give the credit to. The page that is gonna show on SERP is the one its' link is INSIDE the canonical link tag and not the one that HAS the tag.

Why:

Page0 = http://example.com/video123/nice-video-in-london

Page1= http://example.com/video123/nice-video

The canonical link is used so u can make clear to the crawl bots the page is a "dublicated content" and the original is the "canonical link". So in your example the search engine is looking at the page 0 which is "http://example.com/video123/nice-video-in-london" and find a canonical tag. The search engine understands that this is a dublicated content and looks at the link in the canonical tag (canonical=---->original page1"http://example.com/video123/nice-video"<----) and realises that every traffic u are getting from page 1 should be added to the traffic of page 0. And for that reason the page 1 --->video123/nice-video-in-london.<--- is getting zero traffic while the page 0 --->video123/nice-video<--- is getting traffic accounted for both pages AND this page will show on SERP for obvious i think reasons.

Let me know if u have more questions on that or if you need some more details on how or why it works that way.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I understand that link in canonical tag will get all traffic. But what the point to using human-readable URL across the site with canonical tag without human-readable URL, thats get me confused in dailymotion. They not using canonical url as a page url across the site, they using link with human-readable keywords in URL. So if URL with keywords in this case not in the SERP why using human-readable URL across the site, this is the question...

Comment: This is probably just another page with different url that the user created through the process of changing the tittle ,it probably means that the original still exists but you just cant see it by navigating in the site. So to prevent the search engine that will crawl every page no matter the navigation map from considering them as different pages with duplicated contents.

Comment: Have I answered your question;

Comment: @Constantine welcome in SO. Please consider accepting George Stefas answer if it helped to answer your question.